# Export clustered points as coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have been looking at taxi data in a city and wanted to cluster points over a set area to see how many entries would be in each clustered area. My input is a csv of taxi data points [`TaxiID`, `lat`, `long`, `time`] that I have been able to load into QGIS, I then wanted to perform my clustering on these points. I've achieved this fairly easy using the layer properties on QGIS that allows me to display points as clusters and counts the number of entries in each cluster.

[image: qgis screenshot of clustered points and layer properties screen]

However I have not been able to find a way to export these results. Saving the layer does nothing as it just saves the underlying points, not the new clusters. I would ideally want an output file with all clusters displayed as:
[`ClusterID`, `Lat`, `Long`, `ClusterDensity`]

Is there any way to achieve this? I also tried using the *K-means Clustering* from the toolbox but it didn't seem to work only recreated every point in my dataset.

Comment: Have you read up on how clustering works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either by using DBSCAN or by using K-means Clustering. These algorithms are available in Processing Toolbox in QGIS. Once each point is assigned  to a cluster, you can group data by cluster-id and get centroid (lat, lng) and density as no. of point in each cluster.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, K-Means is what i ended up doing. I found that by exporting the shape file i could get the cluster centre from averaging the points myself.